# ZK grid scroll bar problems

Tags: grid, scrollbar, zk

I want to create grid with minimal width whitch depends on it's data. The grid height has to be defined.
And I don't want any horizontal scroll bar.
When there are a lot of data the vertical scroll bar is appeared. It is OK. 
But after that horizontal scroll bar is appeared too.
How I can avoid this horizontal scroll bar ?

It is my code:

```
          <grid height="150px"  hflex="min">
            <columns>
              <column label="one" />
              <column label="two"/>
            </columns>
            <rows>
              <row>
                <label value="Some data"/>
                <label value="Some data"/>
              </row>
              <row>
                <label value="Some data"/>
                <label value="Some data"/>
              </row>
              <row>
                <label value="Some data"/>
                <label value="Some data"/>
              </row>
              <row>
                <label value="Some data"/>
                <label value="Some data"/>
              </row>
            </rows>
          </grid>
```

Comment: What's up with the [crosssite](http://forum.zkoss.org/question/100643/zk-grid-scroll-bar-problems/) posting?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you don't use the native scrollbar your issue is fixed and your data is still all readable :

```
<grid height="150px" hflex="min">
    <custom-attributes org.zkoss.zul.nativebar="false"/> 
    <columns>
      <column label="one"/>
      <column label="two"/>
    </columns>
    <rows>
      <row>
        <label value="Some data"/>
        <label value="Some data"/>
      </row>
      <row>
        <label value="Some data"/>
        <label value="Some data"/>
      </row>
      <row>
        <label value="Some data"/>
        <label value="Some data"/>
      </row>
      <row>
        <label value="Some data"/>
        <label value="Some data"/>
      </row>
    </rows>
  </grid>
```